# Record the file paths of all open documents in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, repeat

I am a newbie scripter in AppleScript.
I have some applications in which I have many windows or tabs opened. I would like to record their file paths or url in text files, so that I will be able to examine them later.
I could get the path of the front document in Preview:

```
tell application "Preview"
    path of front document
end tell
```

But when I try:

```
tell application "Preview"
    repeat with i in all documents
        path of front document i
    end repeat
end tell
```

this does not compile, with the error message: "Expected end of line but found plural class name."

I would very much appreciate for any insight that would help me.

Thank you very much in advance

ni

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain paths to all open documents at once:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Preview" to set filepaths to the path of every document
```

Here's a trick to create a blank file if it doesn't already exist:

```
set f to "/Users/<you>/PreviewFileList.txt"
close access (open for access f)
# set eof of f to 0 -- This scrubs the file if it does already exist
```

The variable `filepaths` will be an AppleScript `list`, which you want to turn into a single piece of text that, say, itemises each filepath, one-per-line (assuming none of your file paths have newline characters in their names):

```
set my text item delimiters to linefeed
set filepaths to filepaths as text
```

This coerces the `list` to a `text` class object, thereby concatenating each item in the `list` with adjoining linefeed (`\n`) characters.  That is to say, this:

```
{"/path/to/file.one", "/path/to/file.two", ..., "/path/to/file.nth"}
```

becomes this:

```
"/path/to/file.one
/path/to/file.two
    .
    .
    .
/path/to/file.nth"
```

This is now stored in the `filepaths` variable, overwriting its previous value (we don't need the `list` object anymore).

Finally, write the text out to file, which will need to be explicitly encoded as UTF-8 in order to preserve Japanese characters when they are decoded as UTF-⒏  So, we do this as follows:

```
write (the filepaths & linefeed) as "utf8" to f starting at eof
```

(Adding a linefeed at the end is convention, and helps ensure that the next time you write to the same file, new content is added to the line below rather than the end of the sentence.)

---

Here's the whole script:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Preview" to set filepaths to the path of every document

set f to "/Users/<you>/PreviewFileList.txt"
close access (open for access f)
# set eof of f to 0

set my text item delimiters to linefeed
set filepaths to filepaths as text

write (the filepaths & linefeed) as "utf8" to f starting at eof

tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to reveal the POSIX file named f
```

Comment: Continued from my previous comment:

2. When I open the created file by double-clicking, TextEdit says it cannot open it because it is not a UTF8 file.
3. When file paths contain Japanese characters, they are all changed into "????????????" (although are in right Japanese characters in the Result window in Script Editor).

Thank you very much in advance for further help!

Comment: I don't see your first comment.  Regarding the issues you mention, I wasn't aware you were needing to handle Japanese characters—this should have been mentioned in the question, although the fix should be straight forward.  It's a text-encoding issue, so rather than writing the URLs out as `text`, we just need to explicitly write them out as type `«class utf8»`.  I'll change the script above to accommodate this.

Comment: I've made the changes to the script, so hopefully that should be more suitable for your needs now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. And I am sorry I have not been clear in my first question.
This time, all works very well!
Thank you again!

Comment: That's great to hear, @NobumiIyanaga.  Perhaps you could reflect this success by selecting this answer and giving it a green tick ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax `all documents`

It's either

```
tell application "Preview"
    repeat with i in documents
        path of i
    end repeat
end tell
```

or

```
tell application "Preview"
    repeat with i in every document
        path of i
    end repeat
end tell
```

or if you need the numeric index

```
tell application "Preview"
    repeat with i from 1 to (count documents)
        path of document i
    end repeat
end tell
```

And `front` in a loop makes no sense because there is only one front document or window

Comment: Thank you very much for these excellent script examples. As they can be adapted for other applications, I think they will be very useful for me.

Thank you again.

ni